# SonarRunner Unrecognized option: views

Tags: plugins, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We are running an "*Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis*" build step on Jenkins with following configurations:

- Target: views
- JDK: (Inherited from Job)
- sonar-runner-2.4

General infos:

- SonarQube Version: 4.3
- Jenkins Version: 1.606
- SonarQube Plugin (in Jenkins): 2.2

Until a few days ago everything works fine, but since then the build is always failing. We are not able to reconstruct if any (plugin-)changes were done on the Jenkins server back then. Nevertheless we ar running nowadays into `ERROR: Unrecognized option: views`. Using other goals works fine, so the runner works in general.

```
18:03:38 Started by user myUser
18:03:38 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
18:03:38 Building on master in workspace c:\Jenkins\jobs\myRunnerJob\workspace
18:03:38 [workspace] $ c:\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner.bat -e views -Dsonar.jdbc.url=myDatabaseURL ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=myHostUrl ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=c:\Jenkins\jobs\myRunnerJob\workspace
18:03:38 d:\Programs\sonar-runner-2.4
18:03:38 ERROR: Unrecognized option: views
18:03:38 INFO: 
18:03:38 INFO: usage: sonar-runner [options]
18:03:38 INFO: 
18:03:38 INFO: Options:
18:03:38 INFO:  -D,--define <arg>     Define property
18:03:38 INFO:  -e,--errors           Produce execution error messages
18:03:38 INFO:  -h,--help             Display help information
18:03:38 INFO:  -v,--version          Display version information
18:03:38 INFO:  -X,--debug            Produce execution debug output
18:03:38 Started calculate disk usage of build
18:03:38 Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
18:03:38 Started calculate disk usage of workspace
18:03:38 Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
18:03:38 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Running "-v" instead of "views" is resulting the following:

```
[...]
17:30:12 d:\Programs\sonar-runner-2.4
17:30:12 SonarQube Runner 2.4
17:30:12 Java 1.7.0_71 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
17:30:12 Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1 amd64
17:30:12 Started calculate disk usage of build
17:30:12 Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
17:30:12 Started calculate disk usage of workspace
17:30:12 Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
17:30:13 Finished: SUCCESS
```

This means sonar-runner is installed correctly. 
I checked the installation of "Views" on SonarQube too. The lisence is activ and if I am running an "sonar-runner views" locally everything runs perfectly.

Any ideas for this strange behavior?

Comment: You should double-check that the Views plugin is really installed on server. It seems not. Please attach the startup logs (logs/sonar.log).

Comment: i made that sure. When i start the "sonar-runner views" on my local PC (which contains an sonar-runner.properties with needed data) everything runs fine. What excatly do you want to see from the log as it is very long?

Comment: the goal is not to check your local box but the server used by jenkins. The installed plugins are logged during server startup.

Comment: When running the command on my local computer everything wents fine -> views plugin is installed correct (as it also in use since nearly 2 years). The problem has been fixed anyways: We just re-installed the SonarQube plugin on Jenkins and everything went back to normal. Nevertheless: thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the problem is still unkown, but after re-installing the SonarQube plugin on Jenkins everything went back to normal. (Down-graded the plugin and updated it afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was linked to a regression in Jenkins SonarQube Plugin 2.2
It has been fixed in Jenkins SonarQube Plugin 2.2.1.
See : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJNKNS-214